# django-pipeline not compressing

Tags: javascript, django, compression, settings, yui

I have just installed django-pipeline into my django application and it doesn't seem to be compressing my javascript files. It seems to be installed properly as the template tags are working correctly.  I'm using manage.py collectstatic in order to compress the files.  Here is my current configuration.  I have also set up my app to use django-staticfiles per the django-pipeline docs as I'm using Django 1.3.

```
 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'site_media', 'static')
 STATIC_URL = '/site_media/static/'
 ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/site_media/static/admin/'

 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "media"),
 )

 STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    ##Turn these on if using django.contrib.staticfiles
    ##'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    ##'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    ##'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',

    ##Turn these on if using django.contrib.staticfiles
    'staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder'
 )

 PREREQ_APPS = [
    # Django
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    #External
    'south',
    'staticfiles',
    'pipeline',    
 ]


 PIPELINE_YUI_BINARY='/Applications/yuicompressor-2.4.7/build/yuicompress'

 PIPELINE_JS = {
    'site': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'js/libs/ddsmoothmenu.js',
            'js/script.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/script.min.js',
    }
 }
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but I'm sure it is something.  I am not getting any error messages or anything, it just isn't compressing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `django.contrib.staticfiles` now that it's included in the standard Django distribution?

Comment: @Cerin You are correct and I fixed this up a while ago.  I am not using django-staticfiles anymore and am using contrib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you setup staticfiles with :

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
```

If yes :

- Are you js files eventually empty ?
- Is `'/Applications/yuicompressor-2.4.7/build/yuicompress'` an executable script ?

Comment: This seemed to be the problem.  I didn't have the STATICFILES_STORAGE setup up properly.  I was under the assumption the default was ok.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you got `DEBUG=True` in your settings? Try adding [`PIPELINE=True`](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#pipeline) to make sure it runs the compressions

Comment: I have tried both of those and still I have had no luck.  When I turn the PIPELINE flag and DEBUG flag on it looks for the compressed file, but still does not actually compress it.

Comment: It sounds like it might be a permission issue. Are you in development or on a production server?

Comment: I'm running on the django development server.  I have checked both the YUI Compressor to make sure that and all dirs to ensure that all of the permissions are set correctly.  My first guess is that it isn't properly calling the YUICompressor but since there are no error messages I can't tell what it is doing.