# django-pipeline with s3 storage is not compressing my js

Tags: python, django, django-pipeline

I'm using django-pipeline with s3. I'm successfully using `collectstatic` to combined my Javascript files and store them in my s3 bucket, but they are not getting compressed for some reason (verified by looking at the file, its size, and its content-encoding).  Otherwise things are working correctly with the combined `scripts.js` that is produced.

Here are the changes I made to use django-pipeline:

1. Added `pipeline` to installed apps.
2. Added `'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder'` to `STATICFILES_FINDERS`.
3. Set `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'mysite.custom_storages.S3PipelineManifestStorage'` where this class is as defined in the documentation, as seen below.
4. Set `PIPELINE_JS` as seen below, which works but just isn't compressed.
5. `PIPELINE_ENABLED = True` since `DEBUG = True` and I'm running locally.
6. `PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'` even though this should be default.
7. Installed the Yuglify Compressor with `npm -g install yuglify`.
8. `PIPELINE_YUGLIFY_BINARY = '/usr/local/bin/yuglify'` even though the default with `env` should work.
9. Using the `{% load pipeline %}` and `{% javascript 'scripts' %}` which work.

More detail:

```
PIPELINE_JS = {
    'scripts': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
            ...            
        ),
        'output_filename': 'lib/scripts.js',
    }
}

class S3PipelineManifestStorage(PipelineMixin, ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
```

As mentioned, `collectstatic` does produce `scripts.js` just not compressed. The output of that command includes:

```
Post-processed 'lib/scripts.js' as 'lib/scripts.js'
```

I'm using Django 1.8, django-pipeline 1.5.2, and django-storages 1.1.8.

Similar questions:

- [django-pipeline not compressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202082/django-pipeline-not-compressing)
- [django pipeline with S3 storage not compressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652271/django-pipeline-with-s3-storage-not-compressing)

Comment: Have you tried with `gzip` compression, we had gone through a similar error , full discussion at https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline/issues/312

Comment: I've found Pipeline is difficult to setup vs. django compressor. If you aren't using a task manager like gulp or grunt, I'd suggest trying that instead.

Comment: @Shaikhul thank you, I had actually already found 312 and was trying to decipher. Can you provide an example for "you would need to change the staticfiles storage url method to return .gz urls (and staticfiles/pipeline template tags depending if you care for clients that don't support gzip). https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline/issues/312#issuecomment-33755035
Also don't forget to setup the proper header on s3 to serve theses assets as being gzipped."

Answer (score 3):

The missing step was to also extend `GZipMixin`, AND, it has to be first in the list of parents:

```
from pipeline.storage import GZIPMixin

class S3PipelineManifestStorage(GZIPMixin, PipelineMixin, ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
```

Now `collectstatic` produces a .gz version of each file as well, but my templates still weren't referencing the .gz version.

To address this the author [says](https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline/issues/312#issuecomment-33755035):

> To make it work with S3, you would need to change the staticfiles
>   storage url method to return .gz urls (and staticfiles/pipeline
>   template tags depending if you care for clients that don't support
>   gzip). Also don't forget to setup the proper header on s3 to serve
>   theses assets as being gzipped.

I adapted [an example](https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline/commit/8b92b41e529c2a418a1e07a7e8aa5d0a93de8e57) he provided [elsewhere](https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline/issues/339#issuecomment-76625632), which overrides the `url` method:

```
class S3PipelineManifestStorage(GZIPMixin, PipelineMixin, ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

    def url(self, name, force=False):
        # Add *.css if you are compressing those as well.
        gzip_patterns = ("*.js",)
        url = super(GZIPMixin, self).url(name, force)
        if matches_patterns(name, gzip_patterns):
            return "{0}.gz".format(url)
        return url
```

This still doesn't handle setting the `Content-Encoding` header.

A simpler alternative is to use the S3Boto Storages option `AWS_IS_GZIPPED` which performs gzipping AND sets the appropriate header.

More is required to support clients without gzip, however.

Also useful are these instructions from Amazon on [serving compressed files from S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#CompressedS3).